# I can ONLY use the "for" loop

Tags: java

How do I get an output like this?
Use one and only one for loop to print the following pattern in one dialog box. Do not use nested for loops. Use only one for loop, not two or more. Do not use any other kind of loop. Do not use a switch/case statement or if conditions. The same code should work for 7 lines of asterisks or 17 lines of asterisks, simply by changing the number of times the loop executes, from 7 to 17.

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
```

My code gives me this:

```
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
```

Here's my code:

```
String message7;
message7 = "";
for (count = 0; count < 8; count = count + 1)
{
    message7 = message7 + "*\n";
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,message7);
```

Comment: Almost good. Try not to append at the end, but at the beginning of the string, and add the line break to the starting string...

Comment: Have you thought about using two `String` variables?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a sample.

```
String message7 = "";
String stars = "";

for (count = 0; count < 8; count = count + 1)
{
    stars = stars + "*";
    message7 = message7 + stars + "\n";
}
```

Comment: @Gatekeeper absolutely not.  the code he shows appends a `\n` onto a string every time, and as i said, this code is not intended to give the full answer.

Comment: @Gatekeepter Theres a subtle difference. See if you can spot it :)

Comment: I've tried to write an answer that forces the OP to understand what's actually going on with it in order to turn it into a complete solution, but apparently that's too difficult a concept for some people

Comment: @Gatekeeper But i definitely did make a mistake,  I had assumed that the OP was doing printing in the loop, where he was actually composing a larger message to be printed elsewhere

Comment: keep calm, just trolling. you are the best. thx god its friday